# How To Show My Site Name On Gmail instead "unknown sender"?

Tags: php, email

I am defining my php headers like so:

```
$sitename = 'My Site';<--Getting Site Name Dynamically So It Must be a variable-->              
$headers  = "From: " . $sitename . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $sitename ."\r\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=$get_charset" . "\r\n";       
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
```

On yahoo mail it works and my site name displayed properly but inside Gmail it shows as **"unknown sender"**. 
So how can I show my site name inside Gmail?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an email address, that's what the fields 'From' and 'Reply-To' are for:

```
$sitename = 'My Site <info@mysite.com>';
```